# Busca MYSQL com PHP e JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

Eu tenho uma tabela no banco mysql que tem um campo `genre` com esse valor:
 
`[{"id": 2, "genre_name": "action"}, {"id": 1, "genre_name": "comedy"}]`

e gostaria exibir todas as linhas que contém o `genre_name` com o valor `comedy`

Meu codigo:

```
function genres(){
    $genres = $this->pdo->connect()->query("SELECT * FROM movie WHERE JSON_SEARCH(genre, 'comedy', '$.genre_name') IS NOT NULL");
    return $genres->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
```

Quando tento exibir o retorno dos valores é exibido esse erro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on
>   boolean in C:\wamp64\www\class\contents.php on line 322
>
> Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean in
>   C:\wamp64\www\class\contents.php on line 322

Comment: Precisa fazer um debug, ver se o problema é no código ou se a consulta retornou algum erro

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/376919/45810 apesar desta pergunta ter apresentado um erro não relacionado a problema específico da consulta, mas sim de estar aplicando um método em um valor `boolean` (`true` ou `false`), ao invés do objeto `PDOStatement`, [como sugere a documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetchall.php).