# Como fazer busca com valores da propriedade de um objeto JSON no PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, json

Preciso filtrar as tags, elas estão separadas por virgula:

```
{
"tags":"Tag 1, Tag 2, Tag 3"
}
```

Usando

```
$busca = 'Tag 1';

  $sele2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM quiz_publico WHERE quiz_json like :json_busca");
  $sele2->bindValue(':json_busca', '%' . $busca . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $sele2->execute();
```

Funciona, porém está aparecendo resultados de outras posições do JSON.
Por exemplo: tem o campo `title`, se tiver a palavra `Tag 1` nele e no campo `tags` não estiver, ele ainda retorna que encontrou. E a página é destinada somente às `tags` e não resultados gerais.

É possível limitar os resultados a tags somente?

**Estrutura do banco de dados:**

```
CREATE TABLE `quiz_publico` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quiz_json` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `tipo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `url` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `publicado` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `aprovado` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: qual é o banco de dados?

Comment: adicionei ao tópico

Comment: "*- aparecendo resultados de outras posições do json*" que outros resultados são esses? você quer que retorne apenas onde o valor de `quiz_json` seja `Tag 1`? Porque ao "bindar" o valor, você adicionou o coringa `%` antes e depois do valor `Tag 1`. Isso vai retornar todas as ocorrências **que tenha `Tag 1`**, independente do que estiver antes ou depois de `Tag 1`. Adicione mais detalhes à pergunta.

Comment: @LipESprY por exemplo, tem o campo title , se tiver a palavra Tag 1 no titulo e no campo tags não estiver, ele ainda retorna que encontrou. porém a página e destina somente a tags e não resultados gerais.

Comment: Ah sim! Saquei! É uma coluna que armazena um json. Daí vc quer filtrar pela propriedade do objeto json. Vou formular uma resposta assim que chegar no PC.

Comment: Gabriel, dei uma pequena reformulada na sua pergunta baseando-me no seu último comentário. Caso algo não esteja conforme, você pode [reverter a edição na revisão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/376650/revisions). ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entendi, pelo seu comentário, que a sua busca está retornando quando o JSON tem `Tag 1`. Independente da propriedade do objeto. Exemplo:

```
{"title":"Tag 1", "tags":"Tag 2"}
```

O problema é que o MySQL entende isto como uma [simples string](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-types.html), ao invés de um [JSON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) <sup>(Data Type)</sup>. Mas de fato, a coluna a ser filtrada **na sua tabela** é do tipo `text`:

```
`quiz_json` text COLL[...]
```

Deve-se considerar, também, que as funções JSON foram adicionadas ao MySQL na versão 5.7:

> "*- the JSON functions were added in MySQL 5.7.8*" - [da documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-functions.html).

Isso significa que o próprio MySQL, a partir da versão 5.7.8, pode filtrar os resultados baseando-se diretamente na propriedade pretendida. No seu caso, a propriedade `tags`.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM `quiz_publico` WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(`quiz_json`, "$.tags") LIKE '%Tag 1%';
```

Na prática:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE `quiz_publico` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `algo` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quiz_json` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `quiz_publico` VALUES (1, 'Tag 1', '{"tags":"Tag 1, Tag 2, Tag 3"}');
INSERT INTO `quiz_publico` VALUES (2, 'Tag 2', '{"tags":"Tag 2, Tag 3"}');
INSERT INTO `quiz_publico` VALUES (3, 'Tag 1', '{"tags":"Tag 1, Tag 2, Tag 3"}');
INSERT INTO `quiz_publico` VALUES (4, 'Foo',   '{"tags":"Tag 2, Tag 3"}');
INSERT INTO `quiz_publico` VALUES (5, 'Bar',   '{"tags":"Tag 3"}');
INSERT INTO `quiz_publico` VALUES (6, 'Fubá',  '{"tags":"Tag 1"}');
INSERT INTO `quiz_publico` VALUES (7, 'Baz',   '{"tags":"Tag 2, Tag 3"}');
INSERT INTO `quiz_publico` VALUES (8, 'Tag 3',  '{"tags":"Tag 1, Tag 3"}');
INSERT INTO `quiz_publico` VALUES (9, 'Tag 1',  '{"tags":"Tag 1, Tag 2"}');
INSERT INTO `quiz_publico` VALUES (10, 'Tag 4',  '{"tags":"Tag 2, Tag 3"}');
INSERT INTO `quiz_publico` VALUES (11, 'Foobá',  '{"title":"LipESprY", "tags":"Tag 2"}');
INSERT INTO `quiz_publico` VALUES (12, 'Foo',  '{"title":"Tag 1", "tags":"Tag 2"}');
INSERT INTO `quiz_publico` VALUES (13, 'Foobaz',  '{"title":"Tag 1", "tags":"Tag 1"}');
INSERT INTO `quiz_publico` VALUES (14, 'Tag 3',  '{"tags":"Tag 1"}');
```

**Query #1**

```
> SELECT * FROM `quiz_publico` WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(`quiz_json`, "$.tags") LIKE '%Tag 1%';

| id  | algo   | quiz_json                         |
| --- | ------ | --------------------------------- |
| 1   | Tag 1  | {"tags":"Tag 1, Tag 2, Tag 3"}    |
| 3   | Tag 1  | {"tags":"Tag 1, Tag 2, Tag 3"}    |
| 6   | Fubá   | {"tags":"Tag 1"}                  |
| 8   | Tag 3  | {"tags":"Tag 1, Tag 3"}           |
| 9   | Tag 1  | {"tags":"Tag 1, Tag 2"}           |
| 13  | Foobaz | {"title":"Tag 1", "tags":"Tag 1"} |
| 14  | Tag 3  | {"tags":"Tag 1"}                  |
```

[Veja funcionando no DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e2JYCC4nNbNztPYphKLRpz/0)

Preciso destacar que as funções JSON, ou pelo menos a `JSON_EXTRACT`, não estão diretamente vinculadas à colunas do tipo `json`. **Mas** recomendo que colunas exclusivas para JSON sejam do tipo `json`, já que ele é automaticamente validado pelo MySQL:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES('[1, 2,');
ERROR 3140 (22032) at line 2: Invalid JSON text:
"Invalid value." at position 6 in value (or column) '[1, 2,'.
```

[Da documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html#json-values).

---

## Filtrando registros no PHP

Caso seu banco de dados seja anterior à versão 5.7.8, creio que a única alternativa seja filtrar os resultados no PHP.

Veja meu exemplo:

```
<?php
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `quiz_publico` WHERE `quiz_json` LIKE :valor');
$stmt->bindValue(':valor', '%Tag 1%');
$stmt->execute();

$resp = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$resp = array_filter($resp, function($arr){
    $json = json_decode($arr['quiz_json'], true);
    return (
        strpos($json['tags'], 'Tag 1') === false
        ? false
        : true
    );
});

print_r($resp);
```

Veja o resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [algo] => Tag 1
            [quiz_json] => {"tags":"Tag 1, Tag 2, Tag 3"}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [algo] => Tag 1
            [quiz_json] => {"tags":"Tag 1, Tag 2, Tag 3"}
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [algo] => Fubá
            [quiz_json] => {"tags":"Tag 1"}
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [algo] => Tag 3
            [quiz_json] => {"tags":"Tag 1, Tag 3"}
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [algo] => Tag 1
            [quiz_json] => {"tags":"Tag 1, Tag 2"}
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13
            [algo] => Foobaz
            [quiz_json] => {"title":"Tag 1", "tags":"Tag 1"}
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14
            [algo] => Tag 3
            [quiz_json] => {"tags":"Tag 1"}
        )

)
```

Repare que o registro ID `12`, que tem o valor `Tag 1` na propriedade `title` do JSON, foi removido do `array` na filtragem (`array_filter()`).

---

## Conclusão:

Apesar da possibilidade de filtrar no PHP, recomendo que, caso seu MySQL seja versão anterior a 5.7.8, utilize para uma versão >= a esta e já filtre diretamente na consulta.

Filtrar no PHP iria gerar o transporte de informações desnecessárias, que **serão descartadas sem nenhuma utilidade**. Para poucos registros isso pode ser imperceptível, mas para milhares, ou talvez milhões, isso vai gerar um **consumo supérfluo** de recursos.

> Leituras recomendadas:
>
> - [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual - 12.17 JSON Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-functions.html);
> - [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual - 12.17 JSON Data Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html#json-values);
> - [PHP: array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-filter.php);
> - [PHP: JSON](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.json.php);